# In Wisdom of Solomon 9 does "Solomon" equate "the holy spirit" with "wisdom"?

Tags: pneumatology, wisdom-of-solomon

9 And wisdom was with thee: which knoweth thy works, and was present when thou madest the world, and knew what was acceptable in thy sight, and right in thy commandments. 10 **O send her out of thy holy heavens, and from the throne of thy glory, that being present she may labour with me, that I may know what is pleasing unto thee**. 11 For she knoweth and understandeth all things, and she shall lead me soberly in my doings, and preserve me in her power. 12 So shall my works be acceptable, and then shall I judge thy people righteously, and be worthy to sit in my father’s seat. 13 For what man is he that can know the counsel of God? or who can think what the will of the Lord is? 14 For the thoughts of mortal men are miserable, and our devices are but uncertain. 15 For the corruptible body presseth down the soul, and the earthy tabernacle weigheth down the mind that museth upon many things. 16 And hardly do we guess aright at things that are upon earth, and with labour do we find the things that are before us: but the things that are in heaven who hath searched out? 17 **And thy counsel who hath known, except thou give wisdom, and send thy Holy Spirit from above?** 18 For so the ways of them which lived on the earth were reformed, and men were taught the things that are pleasing unto thee, and were saved through wisdom.

The Cambridge Paragraph Bible: of the Authorized English Version. (1873). (Wis 9:8–18). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the rest of the scripture into account, the Holy Spirit is consistently something commanded, or sent, by the LORD. It is a possession of the LORD's.

In Proverbs, Solomon refers to wisdom in a similar way in Proverbs 2-3, 8. Wisdom delivers from evil, is a peace upon the man who possesses her, possessed before all creation, a tree of life, gives understanding and knowledge and leads in the path of righteousness. These are all similar aspects ascribed to the Holy Spirit.

Second, the words used for spirit also mean mind. Looking at the Holy Spirit as the mind of the LORD, and we would come to a similar conclusion that its equatable to wisdom. In the NT, Paul refers to having the Holy Spirit as having the Mind of Christ (1 Cor 2). He also refers to the transformation of the Holy Spirit as being transformed by the renewing of your mind (Romans 12).

So, Solomon's equating of wisdom to the Holy Spirit (or the set apart mind), appears to be accurate considering how its used in other aspects of scripture. But, Solomon 'wisely' never places wisdom on equal stature of the LORD. The LORD is the creator of wisdom and is therefore the only truly wise One, and He is the one whom gives wisdom.

James writes about a derivative of the topic. That is praying and asking for wisdom. James tells us to pray for wisdom and that the LORD will give it in an overflowing manner. That's similar imagery to the giving of the Holy Spirit.

EDIT:

Adding to this, the Holy Spirit seems to be an equal split of two things. The power and wisdom of God. Both are required to fulfill His will. So, yes, Solomon's equating of wisdom to the Holy Spirit still stands. Just like equating truth to Jesus is accurate. Solomon's words in Wisdom 9:17 can be equated with wisdom being received through the Holy Spirit.

The Holy Spirit is sent by the LORD, it is a possession of the LORD's. Much like how the flesh of Jesus is a possession of the LORD's. At Jesus's ascension, He is the commander of the Holy Spirit (John 16:7) because He is the anointed LORD (Luke 2:11, 1 Cor 12:3).

Answer (score 1):

Wisdom is listed as one of the seven gifts of the Holy Spirit that Isaiah declares will be bestowed on this messianic 'seed of Jesse' - understood by Christians to be Jesus:

> "The Spirit of the Lord will rest on him—
>       the Spirit of **wisdom** and of understanding,
>       the Spirit of counsel and of might,
>       the Spirit of the knowledge and fear of the Lord, And he shall delight in the fear of the Lord" (NIV Isaiah 11:2-3)

Solomon shows in his passage (and I have used the words from the Latin Vulgate to help illustrate) that the character he refers to as 'wisdom' actually bestows all the other gifts of the Spirit: for what is wisdom (*sapientia*) without righteous judgement (counsel - *consilium*), or without knowledge (*scientia*) or understanding (*intelligentsia*)? This would not be wisdom at all - only an illusion of it. Likewise, wisdom without the courage to act (might - *fortitudo*) serves no purpose.

> "For she *knoweth* and *understandeth* all things, and she shall *lead me soberly in my doings, and preserve me in her power*. 12 So shall my
>   works be acceptable, and then shall I *judge thy people righteously*,
>   and be worthy to sit in my father’s seat."

Even a man who acts without reverence (fear of the Lord - *pietas*), without a willingness to be taught or without wonder and awe (fear of the Lord - *timor Domini*) at the magnitude of what we don't yet or *cannot* know about God and the universe, is seen to lack wisdom.

> "For the thoughts of mortal men are miserable, and our devices are but
>   uncertain. 15 For the corruptible body presseth down the soul, and the
>   earthy tabernacle weigheth down the mind that museth upon many things.
>   16 And hardly do we guess aright at things that are upon earth, and
>   with labour do we find the things that are before us: but the things
>   that are in heaven who hath searched out?"

So 'wisdom', as Solomon understands it, doesn't just bestow the gift of wisdom but in doing so bestows *all* the gifts of the Spirit. In this respect, Solomon's 'wisdom' and 'the Holy Spirit' can be seen as the same.

Comment: Wisdom may equal all the *gifts* of the Spirit, but that doesn't mean that wsidom equals *the Spirit*. Please [edit] this to explain what you think more clearly...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @curiousdannii. Perhaps these edits will suffice.